# Simple menu in Python without using "pip"

Tags: python

All,

I wrote a small python script to parse out data from a log file. I was able to parse out what I need. Now I am trying to create a menu so that user can choose which data they want to parse out rather than all of the log content. I am having a little struggle trying to figure out how to do it, could someone please help me start on making a menu.  Also, I do not have "pip" on my system and I do not allow to use "pip".

I am a newbie to Python.

This is what I have so far:

```
import re

with open('temp.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group()    
    time = line.split()[3]
    ids = line.split()[4]

    try:
        agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        agent = 'agent:'
    try:
        errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
    except:
        errID = 'ErrIdText:'
    try:
        clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
    except:
        clear = 'clearedID:'

    row = [date, time, ids, agent, errID, clear]
    data.append(row)

 for row in data:
 print(row)
```

So I want to make a menu so user can choose if they only want to parse out the date and the agent name for example. **And I'd like for the menu to pass command line arguments instead of user interface**

Comment: A menu **is** a user interface. Do you want one, or do you want it to be completely controlled via command line arguments?

Comment: create the command line argument to get the data from user which data they want to parse, inside the codebase create a function which parse data according to the user input and show to user

Comment: @Ben completely controlled via command line args plz

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sys` package to read the command line arguments. In your case, running the script could look like this:

```
python script.py agent date
```

In your script, you read these arguments with `sys.argv` which is a list of command line arguments. Just remember the `sys.argv[0]` is a script name - all arguments provided by user starts from index `1`, i.e.

```
sys.argv[1] ==> agent
sys.argv[2] ==> date
```

Then, you can use if-statement to control which operation you want to run

```
import sys

if 'agent' in sys.argv:
    # parse agent name
if 'date' in sys.argv:
    # parse date
```

@EDIT
quick example:

```
import re, sys

with open('temp.log') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

data = []
for line in lines:
    date = re.match(r'\d{2} \w+ \d{2}', line).group()    
    time = line.split()[3]
    ids = line.split()[4]
    row = [date, time, ids]

    if 'agent' in sys.argv:
        try:
            agent = re.search(r'agent:\s(.*?),', line).group()
            row.append(agent)
        except:
            agent = 'agent:'
    if 'err' in sys.argv:
        try:
            errID = re.search(r'ErrIdText:\s(.*?),', line).group()
            row.append(errID)
        except:
            errID = 'ErrIdText:'
    if 'clear' in sys.argv:
        try:
            clear = re.search(r'clearedID:\s(.*?)\)', line).group()
            row.append(clear)
        except:
            clear = 'clearedID:'

    data.append(row)

 for row in data:
 print(row)
```

You can do same thing (the `if` stuff) with the `date`, `time` and `ids` vars.

Comment: could you please help show me where I can add these in my code

Comment: @NickGonzales if this gets much more complicated, check out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) - it's already included in python

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly I believe you're wanting the `input` function.

It allows you to get information from the user while the script is running.

```
user_response = input("What would you like to print?")
print(user_response)
```

This will display `What would you like to print?` on the console and will allow the user to type something in. When the user presses enter the print command will then display what the user typed.